# Using a image for an onClick button for Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I am tryng to switch out some standard form buttons and use images instead.  I already did a search here, and replaced my 'fold' button  (works great!)

The Round1 button below is an ajax call that works fine with a standard button.  When I try to change it to an image, it seems to want to submit it(reload the page) , rather than call the ajax function.

This works fine:

```
<button type="button" onClick="Round1(<?php echo $compare_dealer;  ?>)">Raise</button>
<button type="button" onClick="Check(<?php echo $compare_dealer;  ?>)">Check</button>
<input type="image" src="../../_images/Fold.jpg" border="0" name='submit'  value='Fold' />
</form>
```

Here is the line I have added to change the onclick button to an image:

```
<input type="image" src="../../_images/Raise1.jpg" onClick="Round1(<?php echo $compare_dealer;  ?>)">Raise</button>
```

The error I get is:

> Notice: Undefined index: submit in C:\xampp\htdocs\temp\Toronto\Casino\Poker.php on line 320

I believe it's because it's submitting to the same page.

How do I get the form to call the ajax function rather than submit itself?
Thanks.

Comment: You could hook into the form submit event, prevent the default action, and then perform your custom ajax stuff, eg: `$("[FORM_ID]").submit(function(event) { event.preventDefault();// now your ajax stuff}`

Comment: @MLeFevre author is not using jQuery.

Comment: @SlavaFominII Oops, wasn't paying attention to the tags :). Same theory applies though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to listen for form's [submit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/submit).

You can [attach event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var form =
        document.forms['your-form-name']        ||
        document.getElementById('your-form-id')
    ;

    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Call AJAX function from here.

        return false;
    });
</script>
```

You must specify a `name` attribute for your form, or use it's ID with [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById).

The [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) method call will prevent form from being sent.

Also, it could be a better approach to style your button solely with CSS. You can even use the following element:

```
<button type="submit"></button>
```

And selector:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #form-id > button[type="submit"] {
        /* Your styles */
    }
</style>
```

**See this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MgFe8/1/).** As a bonus see how CSS sprites are done ;)